# Store the extracted SURF descriptors and keypoints in *.npy file

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to Python and opencv. I manage to get the descriptors as well as draw the keypoints onto the image but I need to know how to store it for future comparison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may follow [this link](http://www.isotope11.com/blog/storing-surf-sift-orb-keypoints-using-opencv-in-python). I personally use the following code to load and save SURF descriptors

```
def read_features_from_file(filename):
    """ Read feature properties and return in matrix form. """
    if os.path.getsize(filename) <= 0:
        return np.array([]), np.array([])
    f = np.load(filename)
    if f.size == 0:
        return np.array([]), np.array([])
    f = np.atleast_2d(f)
    return f[:,:7], f[:,7:] # feature locations, descriptors

def write_features_to_file(filename, locs, desc):
    np.save(filename, np.hstack((locs,desc)))
```

[EDIT]: add more codes and usage example:

```
def pack_keypoint(keypoints, descriptors):
    kpts = np.array([[kp.pt[0], kp.pt[1], kp.size,
                  kp.angle, kp.response, kp.octave,
                  kp.class_id]
                 for kp in keypoints])
    desc = np.array(descriptors)
    return kpts, desc

def unpack_keypoint(array):
    try:
        kpts = array[:,:7]
        desc = array[:,7:]
        keypoints = [cv2.KeyPoint(x, y, _size, _angle, _response, int(_octave), int(_class_id))
                 for x, y, _size, _angle, _response, _octave, _class_id in list(kpts)]
        return keypoints, np.array(desc)
    except(IndexError):
        return np.array([]), np.array([])

def process_image(imagename, resultname):
    img = cv2.imread(imagename, 0)
    k = surf.detect(img, None)
    if len(k) > 0:
        k, des = surf.compute(img, k)
    else:
        des = []
    k, des = pack_keypoint(k, des) #
    write_features_to_file(resultname, k, des)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @skyuuka, the code you provided is not in python right? i'll try to convert it. The link given shows they use pickle to store but is there anyway i can do it by numpy alone?

Comment: Yes, it is in Python. The only requirement for the above code is `import numpy as np` and `import os`.  By default `np.save`/`np.load` is in `*.npy` format. You can also save/load in text file using `np.savetxt`/`np.loadtxt`.

Comment: So that mean the extracted descriptors and keypoints is array since np.save(filename, array) @skyuuka

Comment: @CY91: Yes, OpenCV (cv2) is using `numpy`. keypoints and descriptors are in numpy array format.

Comment: @CY91: sorry, I just realized I have missed something when copying my previous codes. Now I have made the edits to make it more complete. I have write a separate `pack_keypoint` and `unpack_keypoint` to convert the array to numpy matrix.

Comment: so basically i'll have to write the code above in a new file and put it in the library directory? and call it in the main eventually?

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me:

```
# Initiate SURF detector
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
surf.setHessianThreshold(10000)

img1 = cv2.imread("images/85_hires.png", 4)
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
img2 = cv2.imread("images/85_hires.png", 4)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

np.savetxt("test.txt", des2)

new = np.loadtxt("test.txt").astype('float32')
print(getImageScore(des1, des2))
print(getImageScore(des1, new))
```